# Get Access Token from Goodreads in Windows 8 apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, oauth-2.0, winrt-async

I'm developing a windows 8 app for goodreads (http://www.goodreads.com).  I'm following the web authentication broker sample at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122/view/Discussions.  I managed to get the oauth token and the oauth token secret successfully.

But I'm unable to send it back and get the access token from goodreads. I'm trying to send the constructed URL using the acquired oauth token and token sectret as mentioned in the code below. I'm trying to get the **access token** using the **oauth token** I received from Goodreads API using OAuth.

In the given code "GetResponse2" variable is always set to null from the asynchronous data send method. I think it is because of the construction of the URL but I cannot figure out where it went wrong in the URL. Hope someone can help me.

```
 if (oauth_token != null)                                       
 {

            GoodreadsUrl = "https://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + oauth_token;
            System.Uri StartUri = new Uri(GoodreadsUrl);
            System.Uri EndUri = new Uri(GoodreadsCallbackUrl);

            WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult =
                await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                    WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                    StartUri,EndUri);


            var response = WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData;

            if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
                TimeSpan SinceEpoch2 = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                Random Rand2 = new Random();
                GoodreadsUrl = "http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/access_token";
                Int32 Nonce2 = Rand2.Next(1000000000);
                //
                // Compute base signature string and sign it.
                //    This is a common operation that is required for all requests even after the token is obtained.
                //    Parameters need to be sorted in alphabetical order
                //    Keys and values should be URL Encoded.
                //
                String SigBaseStringParams2 = "oauth_callback=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(GoodreadsCallbackUrl);
                SigBaseStringParams2 += "&" + "oauth_consumer_key=" + GoodreadsClientId;
                SigBaseStringParams2 += "&" + "oauth_token=" + oauth_token;
                SigBaseStringParams2 += "&" + "oauth_verifier=" + oauth_token_secret;
                SigBaseStringParams2 += "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + Nonce2.ToString();
                SigBaseStringParams2 += "&" + "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1";
                SigBaseStringParams2 += "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + Math.Round(SinceEpoch2.TotalSeconds);
                SigBaseStringParams2 += "&" + "oauth_version=1.0";
                String SigBaseString2 = "GET&";
                SigBaseString2 += Uri.EscapeDataString(GoodreadsUrl) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(SigBaseStringParams2);

                IBuffer KeyMaterial2 = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(GoodreadsClientSecret + "&", BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
                MacAlgorithmProvider HmacSha1Provider2 = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
                CryptographicKey MacKey2 = HmacSha1Provider2.CreateKey(KeyMaterial2);
                IBuffer DataToBeSigned2 = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(SigBaseString2, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
                IBuffer SignatureBuffer2 = CryptographicEngine.Sign(MacKey2, DataToBeSigned2);
                String Signature2 = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(SignatureBuffer2);
                String DataToPost2 = "OAuth oauth_callback=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(GoodreadsCallbackUrl) + "\", oauth_consumer_key=\"" + GoodreadsClientId + "\", oauth_nonce=\"" + Nonce2.ToString() + "\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"" + Math.Round(SinceEpoch2.TotalSeconds) + "\", oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Signature2) + "\"";

                GoodreadsUrl += "?" + SigBaseStringParams2 + "&oauth_signature=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Signature2);

                String GetResponse2 = await SendDataAsync(GoodreadsUrl);
                // DebugPrint("Received Data: " + GetResponse);

            }
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Thanks John, I'll update the question soon.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the fact that you never do anything with the `DataToPost2` variable.  I am assuming that it contains some important data that needs to be posted, correct?

```
String DataToPost2 = "...";
GoodreadsUrl += "...";

// Why construct DataToPost2 if not using it?? 
String GetResponse2 = await SendDataAsync(GoodreadsUrl);
```

Comment: Hi, If you follow the web authentication broker sample they are also not using the dataToPost variable they constructed. I just followed the same approach and constructed that. Honestly, I hve no idea, why they construct that.

Comment: @Har - If I was trying to debug this, I would definitely look into that variable and how it is used.